# Is the graphene sheet in graphite considered molecule? What is considered molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry, definitions

[image]

molecule, a group of two or more atoms that form the smallest identifiable unit into which a pure substance can be divided and still retain the composition and chemical properties of that substance. -source Britannica.

I am not sure if this is the answer to my question quote wiki

"molecule is an electrically neutral group of two or more atoms held together by chemical bonds.[4][5][6][7][8] Molecules are distinguished from ions by their lack of electrical charge."

Does that mean the graphene sheets are not molecule because they have electronic charge? what about diamond and quartz? or are they structurally different from molecules like ethanol or water?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suggest reading about [network covalent bonding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_covalent_bonding) (and format references into proper functional ones while you are at it). The question is likely a duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8068.

Comment: oh! Thank you! It's the exact same question I have! sorry for posting another one